# How to setup up Loopback ACL so that all authenticated can create but only owner can update

Tags: loopback

I am using Loopback version 3.24 and want to set up ACL on my model such that any authenticated user can create a new object, but only object owner can update the object.

Currently, I have the following ACL settings:

```
{
  "name": "MyModel",
  "plural": "MyModels",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "profileId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "profile": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Profile",
      "foreignKey": "profileId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

But the API responds with 401-unauthorized when an authenticated user POSTs a new object.

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the ACL configuration. The problem was that I was not sending the `access_token` along with the request.  After I added the `access_token` parameter, the request completed successfully.